# ORMLite performance: ArrayAdapter vs CursorAdapter vs a custom adapter

Tags: android, performance, h2, ormlite

I have relatively small H2 database. I am expecting no more than 100 entries and even that feel highly over the top.

I have a list view with some controls and use an ArrayAdapter with a call to QueryAll() to populate the data. It works perfectly as I can modify the data in the array in memory when a button is pressed and then write the result to DB without having to reload it. But the initial load is surprisingly slow

What I wonder is whether I should rather use a CursorAdapter, since it seems more fitting to the problem or write a custom adapter to make use of the DAO Iterator.

Will there be a performance improvement using Cursor or a custom adapter? In my mind it feels like a custom adapter should give the best performance.

Comment: My 2 bits... I would use ORMLite, the main reason is that code in android for DB work is ugly, hard to read and understand. ORMLight makes it much easier and the code is a lot more intuitive. I have an app that does 100's of read and writes the second it's launched and it takes only a few seconds. Performance is not an issue as ORMLite has a way of handling batch processing. As for your `ListView` consider lazy loading if performance is a problem however an ArrayList with a 100 items in memory should not be an issue.

Comment: Leon, could you post anything about your results?  I am in a very similar situation.

Comment: I ended up canning this project, unfortunately I have no metrics to share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use a custom adapter with 
[Content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Comment: A custom adapter does feel like it makes a lot of sense. I'll give it a go. I am going to forgo the Content Provider, since I am will never have to access the data from another process

Answer (score 5):

CursorAdapter is more appropriate when there is a database because it does not load all the records as ArrayAdapter. It loads only the visible records in the ListView is between 5 and 10. 
So I think if you use a  CursorAdapter you will not have loading problems.

Regards